# Programmatically getting list of child processes of a given PID

Tags: python, node.js, linux, ubuntu, process

I'd like to get a list of all the immediate children of a given PID. I'm OK with using `/proc` but `/proc/<PID>/task/<PID>/children` is NOT precise and may return inaccurate results ([see section 3.7 here](https://lwn.net/Articles/475688/)). I'd like a more reliable method of doing this.

I'd prefer not using a wrapper around a shell command.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use psutils?

Here is an example where I kill all the children.

```
def infanticide(pid):
    try:
      parent = psutil.Process(pid)
    except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
      return
    children = parent.children(recursive=True)
    for p in children:
        os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
```

Comment: Is there a nice port for Nodejs? I could find some attempts but nothing complete.

Comment: Sorry I fell for the python tag. Not up on my Node.js.